# ZF last insert id gives me back '0'

Tags: mysql, database, model-view-controller, zend-framework

When I try to use the function '->lastInsertId()' to retrieve the lat ID of a table I get back '0'.
I can't find the solution. My table is an autoincrement

I try to get it in the controller with this code.

```
$reviews = new Application_Model_DbTable_Reviews();
$lastId  = $reviews->getAdapter()->lastInsertId();
echo $lastId;
```

I hope someone can help me.

With kind regards,

Nick

Comment: Are you inserting a record in the same script? Because the _last_insert_id() functions usually apply to the current connection only

Comment: No i don't insert anything in this script! But what i try to reach. I need the 'id' of the insert for another insert. I need the id of the new inserted review to link it with a row in a other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this stuff is not mention in docs but it works for e.g 
if you have table name 'Book' with PK book_id , FK user_id and 'User' table with PK user_id

```
<<Book>>
*book_id
title
user_id

<<User>>
*user_id
name
age
```

then

```
$userTb = new Model_DbTable_User();
$user = $userTb->createRow();
$user->name = "jason";
$user->age = 25;
$user->save();
```

//well after saving the record ZF populates PK for you so now you have read only access to auto incremented PK simply by $userTb->user_id;

so

```
$bookTb = new Model_DbTable_Book();
$book = $bookTb->createRow();
$book->title = 'php';
$book->user_id = $user->user_id;
$bookId = $book->save(); // this is another way of accessing auto generated PK at insert tim .
```

Comment: It seems to do exactly what I want! Thank you very much, I go work it out in my script! :)